How can I restrict public access to uploaded files in WPForms to ensure data privacy compliance?
I'm currently using WPForms for handling job applications on my website. Since these applications contain personal information, I need to ensure they are compliant with data privacy regulations. However, I discovered that all files uploaded through WPForms are stored in a folder that is publicly accessible. Although the URLs for these documents are cryptic and not easily guessed, they can still potentially be accessed via brute-force attacks.
What I've tried so far:
The URLs are not indexed, and I rely on the fact that they are hard to guess, but this does not fully secure them against brute-forcing.
What I'm looking for:
Is there a way to do one of the following in WPForms to protect the uploaded files?

Restrict or password-protect access to the files so that only admins can view or download them.
Automatically redirect any attempts to access these files to the homepage for all non-logged users.

Any guidance on how to configure WPForms (or WordPress more generally) to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
